# numpy and pysparse floating point representation problem

Tags: python, numpy

I have started using numpy along with pysparse package which interfaces UMFPACK, however there is a problem with the floating point results with numpy. By the way, this is a lanczos eigenvalue solver for structural problems.

When I do the same operations in MATLAB I get different results, well the results are on the order of 1e-6,1e-8 and with MATLAB's representation, I get the right eigenvalues. NumPy and PySparse results are also not that far, at least on the order level, however using them to create a triadiagonal matrix on which to find the eigenvalues is the source of the problem. I could not understand what is going wrong, well the issue is the floating point representation, but how to fix this if possible? I tried to use 'Float64' as my datatype but that does not make a change on the results of the problem. Such as

```
q = ones(n, dtype = 'Float64')
```

One more, what is the most mature sparse package for python, and what kind of interfaces are provided, if any? As told, PySparse seemed fine to me at first sight...

Comment: I think you'll need to supply more information. What functions are you calling that give incorrect results? How are you building the input values to those functions?  (can you post a simple code example that demonstrates the problem?)

Answer (score 2):

`float64` is the default data type in Numpy. You could try using `float128` for more precision, but be warned that certain functions (and basically everything on Windows) will coerce it to `float64` anyway.

I would recommend using `scipy.sparse` for your sparse eigenvector problems. I have tried both PySparse and scipy.sparse, and I would conclude that although PySparse is easier to use, scipy.sparse is more mature.

Here's the sparse linear algebra documentation: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html